# TypeError: res.links.join is not a function

Tags: javascript, callback, shopify, typeerror, monitor

Any idea on why I keep getting this error
I currently am running a monitor script it and it runs fine for a bit, but as long as it detects a bunch of links come in at the same time, I get this error, whereas, if it detects links at a slower pace and maybe 1-2 links at a single given moment, this error takes longer to appear.

```
TypeError: res.links.join is not a function
at send (C:\Users\badboys\Desktop\SHOPIFY SCRIIPT\monitor\monitor.js:408:35)
at lib.getStockData (C:\Users\badboys\Desktop\SHOPIFY SCRIIPT\monitor\monitor.js:396:13)
at Request._callback (C:\Users\badboys\Desktop\SHOPIFY SCRIIPT\monitor\lib\index.js:71:20)
at self.callback (C:\Users\badboys\Desktop\SHOPIFY SCRIIPT\monitor\node_modules\request\request.js:186:22)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
at Request.onRequestError (C:\Users\badboys\Desktop\SHOPIFY SCRIIPT\monitor\node_modules\request\request.js:845:8)
at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:310:9)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at emitErrorNT (net.js:1278:8)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

Comment: Are links stored into array ? I mean does links are the array data type ?

Answer (score 0):

`.join()` is a method found on the `Array` data type in JavaScript.

The error: **`res.links.join is not a function`** most likely occurs because `join` cannot be found as a function on`res.links`.

It's most likely that `res.links` returns something other that an `array`  at some point even though that is what is expected.

Might be with with logging out `res.links` to check this.

The solution would be to handle the case where `res.links` is not an array by not attempting a `join`at that point.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are hitting the [API call limit](https://help.shopify.com/api/getting-started/api-call-limit) and instead the expected response you are getting an error:

```
{"errors":"Exceeded 2 calls per second for api client. Reduce request rates to resume uninterrupted service."}
```

You could solve it by wrapping your monitor function with [valvelet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/valvelet).